# Is there a way we could read the bitmap file that graph500 generates as a graph file?

Tags: c, graph, octave

Graph500 has two implementations for generating graph using the kronecker graph generator:

- Octave - This implementation generates a graph file which is in the form an edge list and is easily changed to a different format as a preprocessing step for performance evaluation or data analysis.
- c - This implementation generates two graph files, one for weights and one for edges but both in a bitmap format.

My question is regarding the c implementation. I am trying to reuse the graph in a different piece of code. I know how to reuse the graph in graph500's SSSP implementation by setting the environment variables of TMPFILE= and REUSEFILE=1, however, I am struggling to figure out a way to read it in some other program.

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/ldbc/ldbc_graphalytics/blob/master/bin/utils/graph500-generator/graph500-binary-to-text.py) script to convert the graph500 output binary to an edge list.

Usage: `python graph500-binary-to-text.py "inputgraph500binary" "myoutput.txt"`

Comment: Tried this. Encountering errors. Made a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75205626/converting-graph500-binary-to-edgelist
. Can someone please help?